# What is the German equivalent of "in press"

Tags: publications, germany, terminology

Just wondering if any German speakers can tell me how a manuscript "in press" is described in Germany. Writing up a German CV but I've never come across this phrase before. It could be a direct translation but I doubt it.

Vielen Dank im Voraus

Answer (score 11):

You can write **"Zur Veröffentlichung angenommen in...".**

I think this is the most common phrase in Germany ("Im Druck" would sound weird).

Comment: "Im Druck" would sound weird - Well yeah because the phrase commonly used would be "In Druck" https://www.google.at/search?q="in+druck"+status+publikation

Comment: @DVSA I don't agree. Most of the Google hits are in fact Austrian websites and Austrian and German grammar do not always agree. In Germany, "Im Druck" is correct and "In Druck" not.

Comment: ok well that might be the reason why I think "im Druck" sounds stupid and "in Druck" not. In Austrian German "im Druck" would usually have a (slightly) different meaning than "in Druck"

Comment: Isn't "Zur Veröffentlichung angenommen in..." rather meaning "accepted"? I agree that "Im Druck" is right but I never saw this anywhere

Comment: Sure, but I think that "in press" (and "im Druck" as well) ist​ a bit s outdated as many journals are not printed (let alone pressed) anymore.

Answer (score 7):

A shorter alternative to @Dirk's answer is **"Erscheint in..."** (literally, "to appear in...").

(Some journals also put manuscripts online as soon as they are edited or even accepted, but before they get an official volume and pagination; these are -- depending on the publisher -- also sometimes called "in press". In that case, I would just treat it as a *terminus technicus* and leave it as is, but the publisher usually explicitly states somewhere how these should be cited exactly.)